# Messagebox and Loadmask

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am showing an alert messagebox:

```
Ext.Msg.alert("Timezone difference","Please keep in mind that data is displayed server time zone, which differs by "+mins+" minutes from your local time.");
```

and in the background, I am loading data using a loadmask:

```
mystore.on('beforeload',function() {
    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        msg: "Loading data",
        width:300,
        wait:true,
        waitConfig:25
    });
});
```

Problem is that the messagebox is closed when the loadmask is opened.

I found no config option to keep it open. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.Msg` is a shortcut for `Ext.window.MessageBox`, which is a SINGLETON, meaning there is a single instance of that. This means, you can display with it a single message simultaneously. In order to solve your problem you could:

1. Create your own instances of [Ext.window.MessageBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox)
2. Use another way of displaying your messages (like rendering some text to a component).

Answer (score 1):

The right way to show a loading mask is to use [mask()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-mask) like:

```
Ext.getBody().mask('Loading data');
```

and after loading:

```
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

Then you wont have duplicated Messageboxes